# Path name can't find in java

Tags: java, resources

- Project File

  - config Folder

    - specificfiles.props

This is where my properties located but still it can't find the path..

I tried this

```
input = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/specificfiles.props");
        if(input==null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find ");
            return;
        }
```

and also this

```
String filename = "specificfiles.props";
        input = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if(input==null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            return;
        }
```

I also tried these things no work.

- `specificfiles.props`
- `/specificfiles.props`
- `config/specificfiles.props`
- `ProjectName/config/specificfiles.props`

I try to search on other questions here but nothing solves my problem..
Please help!

Comment: Is it okay for you to try `PathMatcher` and `glob` syntax? Or using the `java.nio.*;` package

Comment: @Rajarshibasu i'd imported the `java.nio.*;` package but still can't find. and about the `PathMatcher` and `glob`i'm not familiar with them can you give me some references about them?

Comment: Move the config directory into a directory called resources and use "/config/specificfiles.props" as you were doing

Comment: @muzzlator I'm going to try what you said...

Comment: @muzzlator It works i moved it into the resource thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources and files are completely different, don't​ confuse them.

Resources are searched in the *class path*, therefore they are usually not placed in the root folder of the project but besides the *source code*. Or in Maven projects into `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I found out that its the same with the answer on the comments so i'll accept this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :

```
input = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/specificfiles.props");
```

In my project, I use above and it works.

Comment: Didn't work. but thank you for trying to answer my question.

Comment: Things to be tried need to go into comments,post successful testing by user,you can add the same as answer

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I have already an answer and muzzlator comments is the one.